# I want to modify my javascript so that I can put each carousel on how many items to be shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

In my homepage, I use one JavaScript carousel function which is the owl carousel. However, I have five carousels in my homepage only. What I want is to modify my JavaScript so that I can put each carousel on how many items to be shown. Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(
  {
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    loop: true,
    margin:2,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      568: {
        items: 2
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you have a question about using a particular programming language, you should probably tag your question with that programming language, else those who might know what to do won't see your question

Comment: Not sure if what you are asking is to modify the way the Owl Carousel works. You might want to re-word this question to provide a better understanding. However, I suggest you look through Owl Carousel's documentation to see if they have provided for what you intend to do.

Comment: sorry, im just new here. the owl carousel works for me. i have five owl carousel in my homepage which shows 4 items each. my question is, how do i make one of my carousel shows 6 item without affecting other carousel.? please help

Comment: For example you could simply give that one carousel a different class, and then call the initialization code with different parameter values for that specifically. `$(".my-special-owl-carousel").owlCarousel(…)`

Comment: i try that already but ut doesn't work @CBroe

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong, but we can’t possibly tell you what that is, unless you show us what exactly you did.

Comment: Could also be that the `owl-carousel` class is needed to provide basic styling of the component to begin with. In that case, you might have to leave that in for both versions, and then simply use two different additional classes to select the proper elements for the two different initialization calls.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you should something like this:

```
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll('.owl-carousel');

carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
    $(carousel).owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        loop: true,
        margin: 2,
        autoplayTimeout: 2000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        loop: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
            },
            568: {
                items: 2,
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4,
            },
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: what i want is to make my other carousel show 6 item without affecting the other carousel

Comment: So this is the asnwer for your question. Collect all DOM nodes that should contain the carousel and configure each carousel separately.

Comment: so how do i do that @sunpietro